# MySQL dumping and gzipping in a Cron job

Tags: mysql, cron, gzip

What I want is to simply dump my MySQL database at certain intervals and then sync that folder to my S3 bucket when it's done. I am running into the same problem with every incarnation of my scripts.

If I run the script directly, it works fine. The DB dumps and is gzipped with no issues. If I run the script from a Cron job, the script seems to execute in chunks. It dumps and zips between 75-100 meg at a time overwriting the piece that just finished. So instead of ending up with one complete 541Mb gzip file, I end up with one that is only 75Mb and not the complete file.

It's almost like it starts to zip before the dump is complete.

Here is the current script I am using. There isn't much to it.

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date +%Y-%m-%d--%H)

echo Dumping database at production-$NOW.sql
mysqldump --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --routines DBNAME > /var/mysqlBackups/production-$NOW.sql

echo Zipping production-$NOW.sql
gzip /var/mysqlBackups/production-$NOW.sql

printf "Completed backup and gzip\n\n"
```

I have tried adding my env variables to the script but that does nothing, and this is not a script that can run manually.

Any ideas, or places to start? I am going crazy.

Comment: What does the crontab entry look like?

Comment: How often does the cron job run? How long does the script take to run?

Comment: * */3 * * * /bin/sh /var/scripts/backupDB.sh >> /var/log/cron.log

Comment: Right now it is a dev server and has nothing else going on so it takes less than 10 minutes to run. It dumps to a 3.4 gb sql file and then zips up to a 541 mb gz file.

Comment: Do you have the `MAILTO` environment variable set (e.g. `MAILTO=username` at the top of the crontab file) so you will be mailed the stdout and stderr of each cronjob?

Comment: No, I just leave the log files open and watch as it runs. Any errors that pop up go in there.

Comment: `>> /var/log/cron.log` will only redirect stdout.  To also redirect stderr add `2>&1`. (Not sure you would see anything useful though...)

Comment: I am adding that and will check the log as it runs.

Comment: Per advice from [this page](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20/2037) you might want to add the `--quick` option to reduce memory usage and pipe the result directy to gzip: `mysqldump --quick --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --routines DBNAME | gzip > /var/mysqlBackups/production-$NOW.sql.gz` to reduce disk IO.

Comment: Also you might try running the cronjob without the`gzip` command  to see if the `mysqldump` succeeds. If it does, you know the problem begins with `gzip`. If not, the problem is in the `mysqldump`.

Comment: I have had the same problem with out the gzipping. I like the piping right to gzip. I will try that.

Comment: So far, so good. The last 2 times the job has run and piped directly into gzip, the entire file compressed correctly.

Comment: So, I don't know what the actual problem was, but piping straight into gzip has created 8 straight successful dump and zips.